# Proper way of handling this facebook login edge case?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, facebook, security, oauth

I have a user Schema where password is a required field

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
// Some other stuff
password: { type: String,
            min: [8,'Too short, min 8 characters'],
            max: [16, 'Too long, max 16 characters allowed '],
            required: "Password is required"
})
```

however when a user loggs in using facebook credentials I want to create a new user with his facebook email, and a default password, however for safety reasons I dont want to do this as I would have to send this generated password back to the user via email.

I also dont know if saving a new user with a `password: undefined` property would be a good idea.

How should I handle this situation to create a user without a password which is a required field? any help will be accepted thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a [random password generator](https://gist.github.com/6174/6062387) function in the first facebook login, and store another field named isActive as a value default false.

After you send a email to user which includes random password(You will still do not see the password because you didn't see the output from your random string generator function), user will login with his/her username and random password and will create a new password.

After that you can make User's active field **true** so you can understand user is logged in with his/her own password.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  // Some other stuff
  password: { 
   ...
   default: "Call your random generator function here like this.random()",
  },
  isActive: { 
   type: Boolean,
   default: false
  }

)
```